# CardView Layout in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-cardview

Can somebody please tell me how to design a `Material` design `cardview` in `Android Studio` including adapters and layouts file?
If somebody can please also share the source code.

Comment: Your first-step should be to try yourself and if you find any problem in code then go for stackoverflow.

Comment: There are alots of tutorial available , try to use them..

Comment: You can reefer http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/

Comment: Please only use the [android-studio] tag for questions about the tool itself.

Answer (score 5):

First you add gradle file

```
 compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
```

And in .xml file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="6dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Now with Android Studio 3.6.1 the gradle code will look like `implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

gradle file:

```
// CardView
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.+'
```

xml file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/person_photo"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/person_name"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/person_age"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:layout_below="@+id/person_name"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

class file:

```
CardView cv = (CardView)findViewById(R.id.cv);
            TextView personName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
           TextView personAge = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.person_age);
           ImageView personPhoto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
```